# How can I make a Timepicker appear in Dropdown in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, timepicker, ng-bootstrap

On the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/), you can have a toggleable dropdown that only includes the timepicker.  However, I would like to add this using an Angular module for the timepicker instead of using vanilla bootstrap.  You can accomplish something similar with an [NgbDatepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples), however, there are no listed examples for accomplishing this with a timepicker.

I did try to just use the same code and change the mentions of NgbDatePicker to NgbTimePicker to no avail.  The example below yields a `Template parse errors:` where the ngbTimepicker is not recognized as a directive.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="startTime" [(ngModel)]="newEmployeeTime.StartTime" ngbTimepicker 
         #start="ngbTimepicker" [readonly]="true">

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="startTime.toggle()" type="button"><i 
            class="fa fa-clock"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Surely there must be a way to accomplish this that isn't complicated, but I just can't seem to think of it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.1.4"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgbdDatepickerPopup } from './datepicker-popup'
declarations: [NgbdDatepickerPopup]
exports: [NgbdDatepickerPopup]
bootstrap: [NgbdDatepickerPopup]
```

component.ts

```
export class Component {
  model;
}
```

component.html

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

component.css

```
/* Datepicker popup icon */

button.calendar, button.calendar:active {
  width: 2.75rem;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 23px;
  background-position: center;
}

/* Sortable table demo */

th[sortable] {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

th[sortable].desc:before, th[sortable].asc:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat;
  background-size: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -22px;
}

th[sortable].desc:before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/* Filtering table demo */
ngbd-table-filtering span.ngb-highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Complete table demo */
ngbd-table-complete span.ngb-highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

ngb-carousel .picsum-img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 55%; /* Keep ratio for 900x500 images */
}

ngb-carousel .picsum-img-wrapper>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```